# How to set type of generic Java class at runtime?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently running into a problem with Java generics, where the type of the parameter T has to be determined at runtime.

Here's the class having a type parameter T:

```
public class Something<T> {
    T value;

    public Something(T value) {
          this.value = value;
    }

    ... //some other methods
}
```

And here's a method in another class, where an instance of `Something` should be created, but where the type of T depends on the dynamic type of the given object:

```
public void create(Object o) {

    //this is not working, since there is no getType() method         
    Something<o.getType()> s = new Something();
}
```

Is there a way to determine the dynamic type of o and pass it as type parameter to the `Something`-class? It is no option to make use of an `if`-cascade using `instanceof`, since there are many possibilities what o might be.

Comment: Generics provide compile-time checking so that's why it's not possible to do it like you want to.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic type here? Do you mean the actual object being referenced?

Comment: Do you need the actual class of the instance or the type you pass as a parameter? Ie, if you pass a `A` but ultimately the argument is a `B` where `B` extends `A`, what should happen?

Comment: The way you've suggested it's not possible; however, maybe if you tell us *why* you want to do this...

Comment: Can you explain why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am currently working on a code generation project consisting of two sub projects. The first subproject contains the `Something`-class and does the  actual code generation part. The other project delivers input for the code generation and contains the `create`-method. since the code generation should work for arbitrary objects, I don't know at compile time which objects might be passed to this method.

Answer (score 3):

You can parametrize the `create()` method by `K` (just to avoid the confusion with `T`)

```
public <K> void create(K o) {
    Something<K> s = new Something<K>();
}
```

Then, when you invoke the `create()` method several times, here's what will happen:

```
create(Object o)  -> will parametrize Something by Object

create(Integer i) -> will instantiate Something by Integer
```

Comment: This won't be the runtime type of `K` right? What if you pass an `Object` reference holding a `String` object to this method. `K` will be inferred as `Object`. So, no this won't work.

Comment: Whoever invokes the create method will provide the actual type argument here.

Comment: I don't think this works, because you actually need to implement 'create' for every type K that you might create. Plus the fact that at runtime all the Somethings are exactly the same anyway.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I don't think there's a need of implementing `create` for "every type K". Actually, `K` is considered here as "some type with alias K", which means the method is eligible for every type. @Rohit Jain is correct that there's no way to know the runtime type of the object at compile time, though

Comment: Erasure means it doesn't matter: there's no differnece between a `Something<String>` and a `Something<Object>`.  This is fine.

Comment: You don't even need the parameter `o`. It is not used.

Comment: @kocko When you write this method, it has to be inside a parameterized class Factory<K>. Then the argument of the method is the concrete parameterized type.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. Type information of generics are erased at compile time. The type that you use as type arguments, must be known to the compiler. Any expression that gives you the runtime type of a reference, will be evaluated at runtime only, when it's too late to set the type argument.

Comment: Well ... consider using the instanceof operator .. the problem is only unsolvable if the class of "runtime usages" is completely unknown.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Tell me how using `instanceof` operator you can set the type argument?

Comment: See my alternate answer below, please.

Answer (score 1):

At run-time all generic parameters are erased and everything is `Object`.

At compile-time, the compiler checks if the methods used on an instance are those of the generic type of that instance.

`ArrayList<o.getType()> s` is meaningless because at compile-time javac needs to know if it should make an error or not, of the following:

`s.get(0).intValue()`

What if `o` is `Integer` and what if it's `String` ?

Answer (score -2):

If you need to create the right generic type for an explicit small number of classes, you could use the `instanceof` operator ... something like

```
  if (o instanceof T) { x = new Something<T>();}
  else if (o instanceof String) {x = new Something<String>();}
  else if ....
```

Comment: `o instanceof T` won't even compile.